# Distinct Multiple Criteria (Text) - Excel 2010/2013

Tags: excel

Sheet 1

```
Team    Name
Red     John B.
Red     Jim
Red     Mike A.
Red     John B.
Blue    Victor
Blue    Victor
Blue    Victor
Yellow  Mike Z.
```

Sheet 2

```
Red:    Total
Blue:   Total
Yellow: Total
```

What I need is the number of unique counts for all three teams (Red, Blue, Yellow) and counts the names in that group without repeating.

```
Red     3 (John B. appears twice)
Blue    1 (Victor appears three times)
Yellow  1
```

I've tried figuring this out, but I can't get it to work. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Sheet2, cell B1 (where "Red" is in cell A1, "Blue" is in cell A2, etc), use this formula and copy down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9=A1),(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9<>"")/COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9&""))
```

Adjust the Sheet1 ranges as needed.

Comment: If there is someone with the same name on two different teams, your formula returns unexpected results (fractional numbers).

Comment: Thank you so much! This works PERFECTLY! No problem & is even simpler than an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the aid of a helper column.

Assuming your data on `Sheet1` is in columns `A` and `B`,
put this formula in column `C`, and copy down for all used rows

```
=1/COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,A:A,A1)
```

Then, in `Sheet2`, put this formula next to your colour names (i assume they are in Column `A`)

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,A1)
```

Note, drop the `:` from the names in `Sheet2` so they match the data on `Sheet1`

Comment: I tried this & got #VALUE. Is there any other way to do this? I'm trying to count the number of names that fulfill the condition of being part of a specific team colour & putting the total on a different sheet in my Excel book.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a User Defined Function
To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), **alt-F11** opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter the team names as you show on sheet two, let us say in A2:A4.  Then enter a formula like

```
=CountTeamMembers(Sheet1!$A$2:$B$10,A2)
```

in some cell and fill down as needed

```
Option Explicit
Function CountTeamMembers(TeamNameTbl As Range, sTeam As String) As Long
Dim colNames As Collection
Dim V As Variant
Dim I As Long
Set colNames = New Collection
V = TeamNameTbl
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    If V(I, 1) = sTeam And V(I, 2) <> "" Then _
        colNames.Add Item:=CStr(V(I, 2)), Key:=CStr(V(I, 2))
Next I
On Error GoTo 0
CountTeamMembers = colNames.Count
End Function
```

If you really want a formula all in one column then the following **array-entered** formula should work.  But you can see by its complexity why I would prefer the VBA solution -- much easier to develop, understand, and modify or maintain.

In the formula, Team is the range of cells containing the Teams (e.g. A2:A9), Name is the range of cells containing the Names (e.g. B2:B9)  And it is assumed that F2 contains the team color of interest.  If you enter the formula in G2, and then fill down, it will change to pick up the contents of F3; F4 etc, so that is where you place the team colors.  And they have to be exactly as they are in your listing in the Team range.

Especially since you want to have the formula on a separate sheet, I would strongly suggest you used defined names for the ranges.  This will decrease, a bit, the complexity of the formula.

This formula must be **array-entered**:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(IF(Team=F2,IF(LEN(Name)>0,Name))<>FALSE,MATCH(IF(Team=F2,IF(LEN(Name)>0,Name)),IF(Team=F2,IF(LEN(Name)>0,Name)),0),""), IF(IF(Team=F2,IF(LEN(Name)>0,Name))<>FALSE,MATCH(IF(Team=F2,IF(LEN(Name)>0,Name)),IF(Team=F2,IF(LEN(Name)>0,Name)),0),""))>0,1))
```

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl+shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I am not familiar with Visual Basic Editor. Just looking for a formula - possibly an array?

Comment: If you do not wish to use VBA (and there are directions in my Answer which, if you follow precisely, should show you how to enter it), then I would direct your attention to chris's solution.